# Github authenticates but will not allow code push

Tags: git, github

I am the owner for the "project" repo, but somehow I am not able to push to it.

```
user@none ~/rails_projects/project $ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:user/project.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:user/project.git (push)
```

Here is authentication check:

```
user@none ~/rails_projects/project $ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi user/project! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Push attempt:

```
user@none ~/rails_projects/project $ git push origin qa
ERROR: The key you are authenticating with has been marked as read only.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Are you part of an organization on Github that the repository belongs to? It's possible to set up read-only access to repositories for specific members. Perhaps this is the case. https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations

Comment: No, I'm I'm the owner of the repo

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems likely that you have more than one SSH key, and the key that's being presented is a deploy key for the repository rather than one of your account's keys with write permissions. There are two ways of dealing with this:

1. Remove all keys from your SSH agent, and re-add just the correct account key.

   ```
   ssh-add -D
   ssh-add /path/to/correct/key
   ```
2. Use [HTTPS instead of SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-https-recommended). You can do this easily by [changing the remote URL](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/) for *origin* to use the HTTPS scheme instead of SSH.

One or the other of these should work, unless you are simply presenting the wrong credentials altogether.

Comment: Running `ssh-add -l` revealed that the key I thought I was using was not included. So I added it, and now everything is working. Thank you.

Comment: can you please give an example of `ssh-add /path/to/correct/key`. I'm having trouble understanding.

Answer (score 10):

It's a silly mistake I did and the fix is simple.
Just delete the deploy key, add the same private key or new private key again, and this time, just  **`don't forget to mark the "Allow write access" option`**.

[image: Just don't forget to mark this when adding a new SSH key in github]

Comment: fantastic for 2021

Comment: That was my issue.

Answer (score 8):

The error:

> ERROR: The key you are authenticating with has been marked as read only.

could mean that either you:

- you're trying to push to repo by using key which was associated with another repository (e.g. as deploy key), so [check](https://help.github.com/articles/error-key-already-in-use/) by:

  ```
  $ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com
  Hi user/project! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
  ```

  And compare `user/project` if it's the same as your repository where you want to push.
- your key has been locked (e.g. it wasn't used for a long time), so you've to re-confirm it by completing the audit of your existing ssh keys at your GitHub user profile (`/settings/ssh`),
- you're using multiple keys at the same time, check by: `ssh-add -l` (if so, remove them and re-add the right one again).

So:

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

by the following simple steps:

1. Note your RSA fingerprint by:

   ```
   $ ssh-add -l
   2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (stdin) (RSA)
   ```
2. Then check at GitHub if it has been added into your account or repository:

   - for account, check at: `/settings/ssh` (SSH keys),

     - if missing, please add it,
     - if *Key is already in use*, find which other repo using it (see below), then remove and re-add in your account,
   - for specific repository, check at: `:name/:repo/settings/keys` (Deploy keys),
   - if you're not repository owner, check if you're in the right group (with *push* access).

Alternatively use & add new key, [troubleshoot common SSH Problems](https://help.github.com/categories/ssh/) or [contact GitHub support](https://github.com/contact), as they could revoked it for some reason (e.g. by publicly disclosing it).

Comment: Thank you for "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com". Didn't know about it and it saved me right now on how to find out which repo uses a specific key.

Comment: This just happened to me. Same key used for years, can't push to any repo I own. It's not ssh-agent keyring thing, and it's none of the above either. Deleted old key, added a brand new one and same thing. Still no resolution.

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen if you had a deploy key for a repository, which didn't have write access when creating the key and you are trying to push to that repo. When creating a key, don't forget to check the "allow write access" checkbox.